# SQL variable ORDER BY clauses in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query which is currently pasted together from strings in PHP and I want to turn it into a stored procedure.

At the moment it's something like

```
function db_get ($mode)
{
    $order_by = '';
    if ('name'===$mode)
        $order_by = '`name` DESC';
    if ('date'===$mode)
        $order_by = '`date` DESC';
    // ...

    return db_all_rows ("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz ORDER BY $order_by");
}
```

I don't think the name of a column can be an argument to a stored procedure, so it seems that either I'll have to copy-paste the whole query for each kind of order-by it needs, or do some kind of numerical hack like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStuff (IN use_name INT, IN use_date INT, ...)
    SELECT foo, (name*use_name + date*use_date + ...) AS order_by_value
    FROM bar WHERE baz ORDER BY order_by_value
```

I'm not sure which is worse.

I'll prefer the numerical hack to the duplication, unless it will screw up the optimiser.

Will it screw up the optimiser?

Or better yet, can I properly parameterise the order-by clause?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz
ORDER BY
    case when $order_by='name' then name else null end
,   case when $order_by='date' then date else null end
```

The idea is to construct a list of all possible `ORDER BY` columns, and protect each one with a `when` condition so that only one of them is "active".

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks! As far as the +1 goes, it wouldn't count, because I've maxed out for the day. You've got a very cool nick and a matching gravatar, by the way :)